# Pass shell variables to SQL statement

Tags: shell, shell-script, sql, sqlplus

I want to pass shell variables to an SQL statement. Both shell script and SQL statement are present in the same script file.

I want the values of the variables `retMonth`, `retLastDay` and `retPrvYear` in the SQL statement. Below is the code.

```
echo $retMonth  //This prints 07
echo $retLastDay //This prints 31
echo $retPrvYear  //This prints 2015

count=$(sqlplus -s  ${DBA_ORACLE_USER}/${DBA_ORACLE_PWORD}@${ORACLE_SID} <<END
#connect ${DBA_ORACLE_USER}/${DBA_ORACLE_PWORD}@${ORACLE_SID}
set serveroutput on
set linesize 1000
set heading off
set feedback off
define lastMonth=$retMonth
define lastYear=$retPrvYear
define lastDay=$retLastDay
SELECT count(1)
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE partition_date between '01-$lastMonth-$lastYear' and '$lastDay-$lastMonth-$lastYear'
  );
END
)
```

If I execute this, it prints:

```
partition_date between '01--' and '--' \ 0 0] 1 1] 12-DEC-14 1"
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use a **hereis** string `<<END` all $variable expansion is done. This is how your `define` lines can work. But you dont want the `$lastMonth` and so on in the WHERE statement to be expanded, so you need to quote them with backslash. The single quote has no particular effect here as we are inside a hereis.

However, it seems that sqlplus uses ampersand `&` to expand DEFINE variables so you probably want

```
WHERE partition_date between '01-&lastMonth-&lastYear' and '&lastDay-&lastMonth-&lastYear'
```

Comment: \$lastMonth and so on doesn't work

Comment: I dont know sqlplus, but it seems you should be using `&` not $ for these variables in the WHERE statement, so no need for a backslash either.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you've made a mistake with sqlplus variable expansion. You should use `&` rather than `$`.

However you can avoid sql variable at all, directly using the shell variables only:

```
count=$(sqlplus -s  ${DBA_ORACLE_USER}/${DBA_ORACLE_PWORD}@${ORACLE_SID} <<END
#connect ${DBA_ORACLE_USER}/${DBA_ORACLE_PWORD}@${ORACLE_SID}
set serveroutput on
set linesize 1000
set heading off
set feedback off
SELECT count(1)
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE partition_date between '01-$retMonth-$retPrvYear' and '$retLastDay-$retMonth-$retPrvYear'
  );
END
)
```

Note you could have debugged this problem by yourself using `cat` instead `sqlplus` just to print the expanded sql code:

```
echo $(cat <<END
...
END
)
```